# Upper bound on $n$ in terms of $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$, for $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$.

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Assume that we have some positive integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, only we don't know how many. All we know is the value of $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$. Then QM-AM gives
$$n\ge\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2}.$$
In fact, this bound is tight; we have equality if all the $a_i$ are equal. Can we find a good upper bound on $n$ as well?

Comment: No, I mean the $a_i$ can be arbitrarily small ?

Comment: They are positive integers

Comment: Yes but say $a_i=a$ and $a$ is "very small". Then $n$ can be very large

Comment: Correct, but one can still give an upper bound in terms of $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$. For example, we always have $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\ge n$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the "integers" part. Ok so if all $a_i=1$, then $n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$ is attained.

Comment: This means that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ is the best possible upper bound, provided that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$.

Comment: Note that we always have $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\geq\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ anyway.

Comment: Another way to think about this problem is to say we have an undirected simple graph $G$ with a given number of edges and a given number of vertices. Also, $G$ is the disjoint union of complete graphs. I'm asking for an upper bound on the number of components of $G$ in terms of the number of edges and the number of vertices.

Comment: Maybe you can get something out of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1075692/631742

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch the inequality in that answer is equivalent to $k^2-(2n-1)k+n^2-n-2m\ge 0$, where $k$ is the number of components. This gives a lower bound on $k$, not an upper bound.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Well, as I said in another comment, $n\le\sum_{i=1}^na_i$. Note that all the $a_i$ are *positive integers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and assume $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$ to be maximal. WLOG, assume the sequence is increasing.

Suppose there is an $1\le i< n$ with $a_i>1$. The sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_{i-1},a_i-1,a_{i+1},\ldots,a_n+1$ has the same length and sum as $a_1,\ldots,a_i$, but
$$(a_i-1)^2+(a_n+1)^2>a_i^2+a_n^2,$$
which contradicts the maximality of $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2$. Therefore, $a_1=\dots=a_{n-1}=1$ and
$$\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\le(n-1)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i-(n-1)\right)^2$$
for all sequences $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ of positive integers. This can be rewritten as
$$(n-1)^2+\left(1-2\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)(n-1)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\ge 0$$
The LHS is quadratic in $n-1$ with roots
$$-\frac12+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\pm\frac12\sqrt{1-4\sum_{i=1}^nb_i+4\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2}$$
Note that
$$n\ge \frac12+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i+\frac12\sqrt{1-4\sum_{i=1}^nb_i+4\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2}>\sum_{i=1}^nb_i,$$
is impossible, so we conclude that
$$n\le \frac12+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i-\frac12\sqrt{1-4\sum_{i=1}^nb_i+4\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let do this:
$$\forall_i: 1 \leqslant a_i \Longrightarrow (a_i+1) \leqslant (2a_i)  \Longrightarrow (a_i+1)^2 \leqslant (2a_i)^2 \Longrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+1)^2 \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n (2a_i)^2 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i^2+2a_i+1) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n (4a_i^2) \Longrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n (a_i^2)+ \sum_{i=1}^n (2a_i)+ \sum_{i=1}^n (1) \leqslant 4\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i^2) \Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow n \leqslant 3\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i^2) -2\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i)$$
I hope you like this.

Comment: We already have $n\le \sum_{i=1}^na_i\le \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\le \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2+2\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)$.