Formula for number of graphs with $n$ vertices and $k$ connected components.
Is there a formula to determine the number of undirected graphs with $n$ vertices that have exactly $k$ connected components?
If there is no formula, are there better algorithms to determine that number other than brute force searching through all $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ graphs and check the number of connected components?

We know that there are at least $\frac{(n-k+1)(n-k)}{2}$ edges in the graph. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075692/number-of-edges-in-a-graph-with-n-vertices-and-k-connected-components)

Since you write about $2^{n(n - 1) / 2}$ graphs, I conclude that you are talking about labeled graphs. Then a dynamic programming method is applicable to count them.
Firstly let's count the number $c(n)$ of connected labeled graphs on $n$ vertices. From the number of all graphs we subtract the number of graphs in which the first vertex belongs to a component of size $\ell$ for each $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1$:
$$c(n) = 2^{n(n - 1) / 2} - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n - 1}\binom{n - 1}{\ell - 1}\cdot c(\ell)\cdot 2^{(n - \ell)(n - \ell - 1) / 2}.$$
Since we know one vertex of the component containing the first vertex, we have $\binom{n - 1}{\ell - 1}$ ways to select all vertices of this component. Also there are $c(\ell)$ ways to make it connected, and $2^{(n - \ell)(n - \ell - 1)}$ ways to select the remaining part of the graph.
It takes $\mathrm O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations and $\Theta(n)$ numbers in memory. Note that numbers are as long as $\Theta(n^2)$. So as soon as numbers don't fit into basic integer types it takes $\mathrm O(n^4 \log n)$ time${}^1$ and $\Theta(n^3)$ memory. (It doesn't go this way for modular arithmetic or for floating-point numbers, but you loose major part of information.) Also note that each binomial coefficient may be computed using precomputed factorials. On the other hand using Pascal's triangle may reduce multiplicative constant in time and storing two rows only (i. e., $\binom{n - 2}{\cdot}$ and $\binom{n - 1}{\cdot}$) still requires $\Theta(n)$ numbers in memory.
Now to count the number $c(n, k)$ of labeled graphs with exactly $k$ components we can sum the number of such graph in which the first vertex belong to a component of size $\ell$ for all $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots, n - k + 1$:
$$c(n, k) = \begin{cases}
c(n), & k = 1;\\
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n - k + 1}\binom{n - 1}{\ell - 1} \cdot c(\ell) \cdot c(n - \ell, k - 1), & k \ge 2.
\end{cases}$$
And here we have $\mathrm O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations, but still $\Theta(n)$ numbers in memory, if we store $c(\cdot, k - 1)$ and $c(\cdot, k)$ only and either compute every binomial coefficient using precomputed factorials or recompute Pascal's triangle row-wise for each $k$. For long integers it takes $\mathrm O(n^5 \log n)$ time and $\Theta(n^3)$ memory.

${}^1$ If we use linear-logarithmic multiplication and division algorithms.
